# Gradle Sync Failed :No Such Property:Gradle Version For class:JetGradlePlugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

[image]

I had Tried various ways to resolve the issue that are given by the people on the same questions been asked in past,but that is realted to the intellij idea

**I had tried below ways ,but it didn't worked for me -_-**
* deleted the .gradle file and then agained opened the project(in  hope that android studio automatically would installed the needed version of the gradle)

- changed the gradle version and have done trial and error but didn't worked.

***My original version of the Gradle and Android PLugin version are has shown below in the picture.***

**My version of the android studio that I had installed is 3.0.1**

Pls someone help
Thank You
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hey Guys ,I got the answer ,all and only we have to do is go to project structure in android studio and then go to project and then change your gradle version to 4.1 and android plugin version to 3.0.1**

***Click OK***

***And see the magic***